# Limit, pagination in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, pagination

I am trying to add pagination to my current project. I am pretty new to Symfony so I am not sure if there is something out there that can help me build such. My current code looks like this:

Controller class:

```
class MovieDisplayController extends Controller
{
    public function showAction()
    {
        $movies = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:Movie')->FindAll();

        return $this->render('movies/index.html.twig', array(
            'movies' => $movies
            ));
    }
}
```

Twig template:

```
{% block body %}
    {% if movies|length == 0 %}
        There are no movie items available. Add a movie <a href="{{ path('movie_create_form') }}">here</a> to get started.
    {% elseif movies|length != 0 %}
        These are the results: <br />
        <ul>
            {% for x in movies %}
                <li>Title: {{ x.title }}  - Price: {{ x.price }} - <a href="{{ path('movie_edit', {id: x.id}) }}">Edit</a> - <a href="{{ path('movie_details', { id: x.id }) }}">Details</a> - <a href="{{ path('movie_delete', {id: x.id}) }}"> Delete</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        <a href="{{ path('movie_create_form') }}">Add more movie entries</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

This will return all results within the database. I would like to only show 5 results (rows per page) and add paging buttons below the list and I wonder how/if this is possible?

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle?

Comment: I read that it requires MariaDB, so I cannot use that I suppose?

Comment: You can, and in your case you probably should. It does not require MariaDB

Comment: Yes, @Barrosy you can install without MariaDB.

Comment: yes paginators work great, and `findAll` doest not allow pagination parameters

Answer (score 0):

The findAll() function will not work if you want to set limit.

You can try KnpPaginatorBundle to add pagination in symfony. It will work with fine to add pagination.

https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle